# .htaccess rewrite adding server directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

On my website if I type in mydomain.org/services/service1 the address is rewritten to "mydomain.org/services/home/username/public_html/services/service1/". However if I type in mydomain.org/services/service1/ it will go to the proper page.

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [L]
ErrorDocument 400 /404.php
ErrorDocument 401 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404.php
```

My directory is as follows:

```
\HOME
-\Username
--\public_html
---\css
---\code
---\services
---->service1.php
---->service2.php
---\img
---header.php
---index.php
---footer.php
```

What is weird is that if I type mydomain.org/services/service2 without a trailing slash the page loads and appends a trailing slash.

My website is hosted by Godaddy's VPS if that is relevant.

My question is how do I prevent my website from appending my local directory path to the url? And why is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was that my browser had cached an older version of my .htaccess. Clearing my browsers cached data resolved the issue.

My .htaccess file now looks like this in case anyone stumbles across this wondering how to remove file extension and force a trailing slash.

```
#turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

#remove .php file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [L]
```